# matlab fopen tcpip does not work

Tags: matlab, fopen

I am trying to follow the example in the link here:

https://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2011/05/27/transferring-data-between-two-computers-using-matlab/

for transferring data between 2 computers using matlab.

However I am very very !! new to networking so have got stuck.

When I attempt the first part of the example, and open the server socket, using
 fopen(tcpipServer);

MATLAB just sits there forever, in a Busy state.  I've tried different port numbers but still get the same problem...

Please help, and many thanks!

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In networking you have 2 sides to a connection: server side and client side. Server side usually just sit there, waiting till a client asks it to do something.

The same is going on here. You don't have 2 parts in the example, as you suggest, there is a server part and a client part, which must be run in parallel. It first describes the server part, that is wait till the client connects. That's why it 'sits there forever', because that's its job. (`fopen` waits for the client to connect)

To run this example, I suggest you open 2 MATLAB windows, one with the code for the server, and one with the code for the client. Then you run the server code. That way you enter the state where the server just waits. Afterwards you run the client code. The client makes contact to the server (`fopen` notices the connection) and the code can continue to the next statement, which is writing the data to the client. Then the connections are closed.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification...I am a real newbie so I had a total misunderstanding of what I was meant to be doing....doh!!! It works now...thanks again!